# Any JSTL or Spring methods that handles URL like this?

Tags: java, jstl

So I have my JSTL tags like following

```
<a href="${urlHeader}hfv/${curRow.postTitle}">

</a>
```

If the curRow.postTitle is "TEST TEST" and when I click the link, the postTitle segment of the URL becomes "TEST%20TEST". What I want is  "TEST_TEST" instead.

Does it have to be done before the data has been passed to the view or can you simply do it with an available JSTL or Spring tags?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a JSTL tag in "functions" called [replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/replace.fn.html) that you can use to do this.  It works similarly to `String.replace`.  As the example shows, you can do something like this:

```
${fn:replace(url, " ", "_")}
```

Comment: Thanks, I just realised about it too and I was attempting 
${fn:replace(url, "\\s", "_")} instead.